# How to find owner of a device using Hostname and MAC address

Tags: networking

I regularly monitor my network for unknown devices and today found an Apple device with a MAC address and a Hostname. I would like to know specifically, who the owner of this device is. Is there a method for doing this and if so, is it possible as well to find it at times when not immediately active on the network (that is, when it is merely listed in network device activity)?

Comment: Is it a wireless or wired device? If wireless - black list the MAC address, and you will find someone complaint about unable to connect to wireless. If wired - trace the wire to the device?

Comment: And no, it'll probably be impossible to find it when it's turned off.

Comment: It's hard, particularly for a wireless device but you may be able to work out the location of the device (and thus it's owner) by looking at the signal strength and moving the Access Point (maybe having multiple overlapping APs and disconnecting each in turn to help?)

Answer (score 0):

If you have an inventory software like GLPI you can assign stuff to users and "owner", so you could have a look to whom the computer belongs or to whom it is assigned to. If you don't find it in the system, it's very likely not a company computer, so it should probably not be on the network.
Otherwise you can try Darius method.

Comment: What is the Darius Method?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/1376605/how-to-find-owner-of-a-device-using-hostname-and-mac-address/1376619?noredirect=1#comment2074416_1376605